# Signalfx formula set 0 if no timeseries found

Tags: statistics, splunk, signalfx

I have the following formula in a signalfx chart, but it's not showing any results because `F` has 0 timeseries. How can I display it as 0 instead of this blank line.

```
F = data('myapi.job.count', filter=filter('environment_type', '*') and filter('execution_status', 'failed'), rollup='sum', extrapolation='zero').sum().sum(over='7d').publish(label='F', enable=False)
A = (F).publish(label='A')
```

[image]

Comment: If you self-answer, you really should make sure that your answer clearly follows from your question. Please [edit] the question (or answer) to help bridge that gap.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was to use `fill(0)` so the complete solution would be:

```
F = data('myapi.job.count', filter=filter('environment_type', '*') and filter('execution_status', 'failed'), rollup='sum', extrapolation='zero').sum().sum(over='7d').fill(0).publish(label='F', enable=False)
A = (F).publish(label='A')
```

Comment: Link to the docs here: https://dev.splunk.com/observability/docs/signalflow/methods/fill_stream_method/